# Javascript Closures Object Property Accessor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, closures, accessor

I am having a problem with closures I think. I am really new to doing OOP JavaScript ONLY (I started this week...) but I have used JavaScript for little DOM manipulation stuff here or there and JQuery magic quite a few times. I am looking for a solution to my problem that does not involve changing my criteria because I want to try and finally learn proper JavaScript. My criteria is that I want the solution to be able to maintain my encapsulation and Java style publicly accessed private variables. My criteria also needs the solution to be able to teach me a bit about closures without repeating the examples at [thisPage]:[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111) .

I have scoured the internet for a solution to my problem and the videos I have been finding, the books I red in school, the net pages I have red and the S.O. posts I have gone through have not yet shown me a good answer to why this is happening. That or I just really cannot grasp closures or whatever this problem is...

I have a class like this:

```
var Animal = {
    $name: "Blank",
    $age: -1,
    setName: function(n) {this.name=n;},
    setAge: function(a) {this.age=a;}
};
```

To which I then afterwards call...

```
Moose.prototype = Object.create(Animal);
Moose.prototype.constructor = Moose;
function Moose(newName, newAge) {
    this.setName(newName);
    this.setAge(newAge);
}
```

The `this` in `this.setName()` does what I want and finds Animal and adds a name to my moose without causing its Moose brethren to be also called "moosey moose mcDonkeybutt" or something....

I can successfully then, in console, create two 'Meese' or Mooses if you will and each has their own separated values. Like...

```
m1 = new Moose("MooseyMoose", 420);
m2 - new Moose("MooseMcTingles", 69);
```

And m1 wouldn't have the same values as m2 when inspected. Which is what I would expect from the other languages I have used over the years.... However this is where I get confused or at least glaring at my computer like, whoa, "what the douce?"

I want to add some kind of ability to gauge how each animal is moving over time. So I thought, hey, why not take this time to use the awesome power and simplicity of object literals to store this inside my class.... like so....

```
var Animal = {
    $name: "Blank",
    $age: -1,
    $position: {x:-1,y:-1},
    setName: function(n) {this.name=n;},
    setAge: function(a) {this.age=a;},
    getName: function() { return this.name; }
};
```

So I add in my accessor with a bit of extra load...

```
var Animal = {
    $name: "Blank",
    $age: -1,
    position: {x:-1,y:-1}, //I have tried $ and without
    setName: function(n) {this.name=n;},
    setAge: function(a) {this.age=a;},
    getName: function() { return this.name; },

    //New Accessor
    setPosition: function(newX, newY) {
        this.position.x = newX;
        this.position.y = newY;
    }
};
```

As I am sure the experienced programmers are reading at this point and saying... what an idiot. Problem is I have not read, searched or found the answer to have my AHH HA!! moment  to this next part. If you already guessed what I am gonna have wrong you prolly should answer. **Why on earth is this causing both `m1` and `m2` to have the same shared values on position now?** Its not because its publicly declared I have tried with a private scope as well and it just makes it even harder for the `this` to find the correct prototype.

I have tried so SO many version of code on this block to try and figure out why I can't seem to store my position as a simple little object literal with easy access... I need all instances of Moose() to not be able to change each others position by using the `setPosition()` function above....

Also. I have tried converting it all to a `function` object rather than a var Object and I have also tried removing many combo's of `this`'s that I knew weren't hitting the scope I need, however no luck yet. I have also tried removing the use of the `.create()` method and switched to the `new` keyword and also no luck.

EDIT: to the ppl replying....  like I said I have tried it all including adding getter setter methods to the position variable. It doesnt help at all it still shares the value....

Comment: Answerers, please skip reading the first three paragraphs... That is totally not relevant to the question.

Comment: It's pretty annoying to see the function declaration for *Moose* after assigning to its prototype and other stuff. It's much easier to understand the code if it's written in a logical sequence.

Comment: @RobG yeah that should definitely be switched around.

Comment: Why does it matter this isnt a compiled language it is an interpereted language.... sequence means nothing.

Comment: @thefourtheye did it hurt you to read two paragraphs? I was told to elaborare on my question as much as possible... those paragraphs let people know what answers NOT to bother giving me....

Comment: What is "*Java style publicly accessed private variables*"? Regardless, you probably should not, and use JavaScript style instead…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take this step by step.

> Do you have a member called `position` defined in `Moose` constructor?

No.

> Then how the objects of `Moose` get `position`?

Through inheritance. Since `Moose.prototype` is set to be an Object of type `Animal`, when you say `m1.position`, JavaScript searches `m1` for `position` and it moves up in the inheritance ladder to  finding it in `Moose.prototype` Object. This searching is common for both `m1` and `m2`. So, they both find the same `Animal` object in `Moose.prototype`. You can confirm that, like this

```
console.log(m1.position === m2.position);
# true
```

> How do we get around this?

Simple. Don't define the member variables of the child objects in the Parent objects. Just move the definition of `position` to `Moose` constructor. Now, when the JavaScript searches for `m1.position` and `m2.position`, they both will have their own copy of `position` :-)

Comment: Nice answer. OP, you may find this link helpful to explain prototypal inheritance http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/

Comment: I know I can put it in the moose constructor but I just thought it looked like horrible code coming from java and c#. To repeat that variable creation when it can belong to all created from the inheritance seemed like I was repeating things too much.

Comment: So in other words objects are passed by ref no matrer what even if they live in an instanced parent object being used by kids? I guess I'm not used to how javascript instances its objects such as Animal.

Comment: No, if you want each instance to have its own position object, then you need to create a new position object for each instance. This is not "horrible code", this is just how it is done.